# TYPO3 - changing own Field on edit page by custom content element

Tags: php, typo3

I created a custom content element with TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21, but I have a problem.

**Problem: showing up same Fields on every edit page of content elements.**

I want to use own fields only on my custom content element (for my flipbox-content element). But if I select e.g. a regular text element, then I can see my own fields on the edit page by the text element too.

I wrote the codes in `TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
###############################################
#                    Front side               #
###############################################
// front side header
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    [
       'tx_pagesaddfields_frontsideheader' => [
          'exclude' => 0,
          'label' => 'Front side header',
          'config' => [
             'type' => 'text',
             'renderType' => 'input',
             'items' => [
                [
                   0 => '',
                   1 => ''
                ]
             ],
          ],
       ],
    ]
 ); 
 
 // front side bodytext
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    [
       'tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext' => [
          'label' => 'Front side bodytext',
          'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'enableRichtext' => true,
          ],
       ],
    ]
 );
 
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'general',
    'tx_pagesaddfields_frontsideheader, tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext',
    'after:tx_container_parent'
 ); 
 
 
 ###############################################
 #                Back side                    #
 ###############################################
 
 // back side header
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    [
       'tx_pagesaddfields_backsideheader' => [
          'exclude' => 0,
          'label' => 'Back side header',
          'config' => [
             'type' => 'text',
             'renderType' => 'input',
             'items' => [
                [
                   0 => '',
                   1 => ''
                ]
             ],
          ],
       ],
    ]
 );
 
 // back side bodytext
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    [
       'tx_pagesaddfields_backsidebodytext' => [
          'label' => 'Back side bodytext',
          'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'enableRichtext' => true,
          ],
       ],
    ]
 );
 
 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'general',
    'tx_pagesaddfields_backsideheader, tx_pagesaddfields_backsidebodytext',
    'after:tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext'
 );
```

I know because I wrote "addTCAcolumns('tt_content'). But I don't know how I can rewrite them to let show up my new fields only on my custom edit page.

Is it the right page to chage it?:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html
(by exanple1) and
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User/Index.html#columns-user?

I tried to do it, but it didn't work on my site. Unfortunately, I don't have enough experiences with PHP... If you know other website or if you can explain here, please write it down here.

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please split this in posts, one question per post. I'll answer you to the first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to add one file into `TCA/Overrides/` per custom content element. The name is up to you, TYPO3 reads all `.php` files in this folder. `content_element_<your_ctype>.php` or `tt_content_<your_ctype>.php` are used as name quite often.

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/203_content_element_card_group.php

Here you can see how it is done in the `bootstrap_package` for the custom content element with the CType `card_group`

In line 42 `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['card_group']` the configuration is limited to `['(C)type']['card_group']` and the `'showitem' => '` tells TYPO3 what and how to show fields for this content element.

From line 70 on you can see how to set a new field, in line 49 you can see how it was added.